# DynamoDB Exception element does not match the schema

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update existing token item with `last_accessed_on` column (which is new).  I tried below code which is failing.
Please point me what is wrong here.

```
//dynamoDB is initialized with config and it is good.
Table  table = dynamoDB.getTable("Token");
UpdateItemSpec  updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                .withPrimaryKey("GUID", "guidHashed")
                .withUpdateExpression("set #name = :val1")
                .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#name", "last_accessed_on"))
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withLong(":val1", System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Below is the DTO object.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Token")
public class TokenItem {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "GUID")
    private String guid;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "type")
    private String type;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "last_accessed_on")
    private long lastAccessedOn;

    //getter and setters
}
```

**Error:**

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: FNEPHSAEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1660)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3768)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3737)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeUpdateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3448)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3416)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.UpdateItemImpl.doUpdateItem(UpdateItemImpl.java:102)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.UpdateItemImpl.updateItem(UpdateItemImpl.java:86)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.updateItem(Table.java:225)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the range key from your `UpdateItemSpec`. You need to use [`withPrimaryKey(String hashKeyName, Object hashKeyValue, String rangeKeyName, Object rangeKeyValue)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/UpdateItemSpec.html#withPrimaryKey-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) instead of the method that accepts only the hash key. Also, `type` is a [reserved word in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html), so you will need to add it to the NameMap.

The fixed UpdateItemSpec would be like this.

```
Table  table = dynamoDB.getTable("Token");
UpdateItemSpec  updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey("GUID", ":guid", "#type", ":type")
            .withUpdateExpression("set #name = :val1")
            .withNameMap(new NameMap()
                    .with("#name", "last_accessed_on")
                    .with("#type", "type"))
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withLong(":val1", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .withString(":guid", /* put the guid here */)
                    .withString(":type", /* put the type here */));
```

Comment: Thank you @Matthew it is working now.  The `type` i just used it when i was posting question here, but good to know that it is a reserved word.  Again if i understand correctly it only updates particular field not the complete item. am i right ?

Comment: @Kiran That’s correct, this will only update the attributes that are specifically mentioned in the update expression.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
DynamoDBMapper dyanmoDbMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client, yourConfig);

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Token> qExp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Timesheet>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression(" GUID =:GUID  and type =:type")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(mapOfGuiAndTypeValues).withScanIndexForward(false)
            .withConsistentRead(false);


QueryResultPage< Token> queryPage= dyanmoDbMapper.queryPage(Token.class, qExp);
```

once you have retrieved the object then update with last access value and save

```
dyanmoDbMapper.save(updatedObject);
```

Comment: note in your code you are note using the range key (DynamoDBRangeKey) type